# Stats Model. get unique session_ids, and then group by hour of day

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

im having some difficulty coming up with a nice way of compiling some stats for a csv.

I have a stats table that has a session_id column and a created_at column as well as a couple of other associations for some belongs_to's.

What i'm trying to achieve is nicely formatted result that counts unique session_ids (on occasion there are repeated sessions. i need to not count these) and then group these numbers into the hour of day the appeared.

currently if i do this:

```
Stat.group("date_format(created_at, '%H')").count
```

it returns this

```
=> {"00"=>100, "01"=>77, "02"=>80, "03"=>88, "04"=>96, "05"=>98, "06"=>104, "07"=>87, "08"=>80, "09"=>67, "10"=>92, "11"=>67, "12"=>83, "13"=>91, "14"=>72, "15"=>64, "16"=>61, "17"=>169, "18"=>90, "19"=>83, "20"=>119, "21"=>94, "22"=>95, "23"=>82}
```

which is perfect for returning all the results - which i do need.

but what i need to do is also figure out how to combine something like this- which only returns the unique sessions

```
Stat.select(:session_id).map(&:session_id).uniq
```

i was messing around in mysql and came up with this- which looks to do what i need. but i cannot figure how how to make it play well with active record.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, date_format(created_at, '%H') AS date_format_created_at_h,COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS session FROM my_db.stats GROUP BY date_format(created_at, '%H')
```

can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: If you just need the raw data then sometimes it is best to push AR out of the way and just do a `connection.select_rows(sql_goes_here)`, you might need to sort out the string-to-whatever type conversions yourself but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: oh. interesting. i think that worked really nicely.  im going to mess with it some more.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
2.0.0-p195 :156 > Stat.group("strftime('%S',created_at)").count
(3.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, strftime('%S',created_at) AS strftime_s_created_at FROM "stats" GROUP BY strftime('%S',created_at)
=> {"24"=>105, "25"=>80, "26"=>88, "27"=>83, "28"=>86, "29"=>80, "30"=>84, "31"=>70, "32"=>68, "33"=>73, "34"=>123, "35"=>84, "36"=>74, "37"=>59, "38"=>80, "39"=>77, "40"=>82, "41"=>79, "42"=>88, "43"=>73, "44"=>64, "45"=>82, "46"=>86, "47"=>87, "48"=>37}
```

Using `select COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))` to gain uniq count:

```
2.0.0-p195 :157 > Stat.select("strftime('%S',created_at) as time").select('COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id)) as uniq').group("strftime('%S',created_at)").map{|x| {x.time => x.uniq}}.reduce(:merge)
Stat Load (5.4ms)  SELECT strftime('%S',created_at) as time, COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id)) as uniq FROM "stats" GROUP BY strftime('%S',created_at)
=> {"24"=>44, "25"=>53, "26"=>52, "27"=>59, "28"=>61, "29"=>61, "30"=>64, "31"=>52, "32"=>49, "33"=>57, "34"=>102, "35"=>69, "36"=>55, "37"=>42, "38"=>65, "39"=>59, "40"=>65, "41"=>63, "42"=>69, "43"=>56, "44"=>47, "45"=>67, "46"=>70, "47"=>69, "48"=>22}
```